# Get List<DateTime> from DataTable have 1 date column

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have a stored procedure which returned a datatable which have only 1 date column. I want to fill List from that datatable without using a loop.

Comment: And what issue you are facing in that?

Comment: I'm certain you've made an attempt at solving this, right? Please show the code that you tried unsuccessfully, it's often just a tiny fix to your code that's required.

Comment: By "without iterating on it" do you mean not using loop syntax in your code, therefore allowing LINQ, row operations etc? Or do you actually mean not iterating over it period, including doing so in the external code?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya no I didn't face any error. Was just asking for possibilities.

Comment: @BartłomiejPopielarz yes no loop syntax in my code. Linq etc are fine.

Comment: You can access directly by index `dt.Rows[0][0];`

Comment: @AndréSanson Yes I can but I want list not a single date.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<DatetTime> = (from DataRow row in dt.Rows select (DateTime)row["ReportDate"]).ToList();
```

Comment: This is correct approach.

Comment: If the sole purpose of the existence of the data table is as a means to extract the data into the list, you can skip it all together using any class derived from DbDataReader (which implements IEnumerable) as a base for a LINQ expression.
In the process you'll get rid of all the intermediary allocations done to populate the data table.